# How to use Azure AppRoles in Blazor Server with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, roles, blazor-server-side

I have an up and running .NET 5 Web-API with a Blazor Server Client in Production. I'd like to switch from Individual User Accounts to Azure AD using App Roles to authenticate specific Users in my Controllers. I found lots of Information regarding Webassembly but none for Blazor Server.

Has somebody a working Solution for a .NET 5/6 Web-Api with a Blazor Server Client and integrating Azure App Roles?

Apps are already registered in the Azure Portal and so forth, I just need to know how to pass the App Roles specific stuff to my API, so my Controller can work with the [Authorize("Admin")] stuff. I suspect it will use Bearer Tokens aswell.

**Edit:**
Thanks a lot for reading. So I figured out that if I use something like this in my Controller only using the [Authorize] Attribute without any roles:

```
 var identities = HttpContext.User.Identities.ToList();
            foreach (var item in identities)
            {
                if (item.RoleClaimType == "admin")
                {
                    // return or do something
                }
            }
```

It would just work fine but there has to be some smoother solution for this or am I doing this completly wrong? When I look at the WASM Samples, they pick up the AppRoles with their token and the Controller simply can use the [Authorize(Roles = "xyz")] Attribute. What am I missing here? :/

Btw, this is how my Program.cs looks right now:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType =
                    "admin";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "doku";
            },
            options => { builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); });
```

Thank you guys/gals <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the given references are of use in your case.

A SERVER API app can authorize users to access secure API endpoints with authorization policies for security groups, AAD Administrator Roles, and App Roles

- In Program.cs of a SERVER app, specify the claim as roleclaim

example:

```js
     builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = 
                    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role";
            },
            options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); });
```

- Then you can use admin role on authorization controller to access

  [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
- Here in [App roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/azure-active-directory-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#app-roles) section you can see the configuration for both
  server and client.
- Edit the app role in the manifest editor in portal  and then give
  proper api permissions , expose scopes and grant permission for admin
  consent >see  [Add app roles and get them from a token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#example-application-app-role) .And the
  procedural logic must contain those scopes required by api.

> Note : The appRoles manifest property of both the client and the
> server Azure portal app registrations must include the same configured
> roles.

Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/azure-active-directory-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authorize-server-apiweb-api-access) for more detailed information which guides for both server and client apps.

**Other references:**

1. [using-app-roles-with-AAD-blazor-server-client scenario | codemaze.com](https://code-maze.com/using-app-roles-with-azure-active-directory-and-blazor-webassembly-hosted-apps/)
2. [quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)
3. [quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)

Comment: Thanks for your wonderfully detailed Answer. I just updated the Post with some more Details. If you could give me another hint, that'd be awesome :)

Comment: Holy crap, I am moron. Now I got it. Thanks a lot :D