# Get Azure app service roles in a blazor server

Tags: azure-web-app-service, authorization, blazor-server-side

I used the out-of-the-box config to connect my Blazor app to AAD for SSO and that works great.  Now, I am trying to use Azure App Service Roles to authorize users in various parts of the application. I have registered the app in Azure and created two roles.  These roles are each assigned AAD groups.
[image]

When I look in the manifest the roles are there so it seems to configured correctly.

```
"appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User"
            ],
            "description": "this is the role description ",
            "displayName": "Owner",
            "id": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "Owner"
        },
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User"
            ],
            "description": "this is the role description",
            "displayName": "Approver",
            "id": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "Approvers"
        }
    ],
```

My problem is getting these roles in my Blazor server app. I was following this blog to get the Roles configured properly (https://code-maze.com/using-app-roles-with-azure-active-directory-and-blazor-webassembly-hosted-apps/) but its for WASM and I got the point of adding to the app roles and it wanted this `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;` which I don't have in a server app.

I was reading about using MS Graph to get groups from AAD but that seems very complicated and much more than I need.

This one looked promising but I don't think its using the App Service Roles.
[How to use Azure AppRoles in Blazor Server with Azure Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69887531/how-to-use-azure-approles-in-blazor-server-with-azure-active-directory)

Thanks for any direction you can provide

**EDIT:**
I found this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-7.0
but I'm in .Net6 and it doesn't seem to work.  It doesn't recognize .AddDefaultIdentity.  I do have `builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();` but not sure how to add my azure roles?

Is it this, with some role name? `builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>() .AddRoles(???);`

Answer (score 0):

After a LOT of reading and two different headaches, I learned that the Azure roles come through the user Identity as a claim type of "role".  I'm still learning but to see the claims I added

```
 [CascadingParameter]
 private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationState { get; set; }
```

and in `OnInitialized`

```
 var authState = await authenticationState;
 var test = authState.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Value == "Owner");
```

You can examine the Claims to see all the claims the user has.  "Owner" is the name of the role I was looking for.  And this worked.

I think you also have to wrap the contents of the App.razor file in a `<CascadingAuthenticationState>`

Like so:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

the only hangup I have now is I can't get the `[Authorize(Roles="Owner")]` attribute to work.  I'll work that in another question if I can't figure it out.