# Blazor Server Azure App Service Easy Auth

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I have a .Net 6.0 Blazor Server app running in an Azure App Service. Azure gives you the ability to setup your App Service so that it does the authentication for you. This is called Easy Auth. You can configure Easy Auth with various identity providers, in my case I'm using Azure Active Directory. Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) explaining App Service Easy Auth in more detail.

The concept of this is that you do not need to add any authentication middleware code to your application, the App Service handles all of it for you.

**I am struggling to figure out how to access the currently authenticated user and their roles from my Blazor Server code.**

For a Blazor WebAssembly app running in an App Service configured with Easy Auth, when you make a call to your controllers the App Service auto-magically puts the authenticated users information in a header and you can access it that way.

I tried following this [guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76310124/get-azure-app-service-roles-in-a-blazor-server) post, but I could not access the authenticated user. He was also struggling to access the roles of a user.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Are you able to authenticate the user ?

Comment: Can you please share the code of your `Program.cs` file and the razor pages.

Comment: @Harshitha, the app service does successfully authenticate the user. I currently do not have an authentication logic in my program class for that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-user-identities#access-user-claims-using-the-api), we are able to use `/.auth/me` to reach the signed in user profile after enabling easy auth.

[image]

Since we are now using Azure AD as the identity platform, and we are able to access the [id token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/id-token-claims-reference#payload-claims) now, so we could try to gather the user role by decoding the id token. Or we could use the access token to call graph api and [obtain the user role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Yes but the Blazor server code cannot access /.auth/me since its running on the server. It gets a 401 unauthorized. You can only access that endpoint from the browser

Comment: I found a good answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1373805/how-to-get-user-name-for-blazor-server-application), and since you mentioned that `Blazor server code cannot access /.auth/me since its running on the server`, so I trust if I call this api via js, it should be ok. So write a js method which is used to call this api, and we can call this js method in `protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{if (firstRender){module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Pages/Index.razor.js");}}` then trigger this method

Comment: Thats super clever, thanks!